# Cant change length of a carousel in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, size, carousel

I am building a website with bootstrap and I added a carousel to show some pictures, but I can't make them wider. I have tried to change the values of w- within tags, but all it does is show picture in full size or stay the same I want the picture to be wider by a third of its width.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide bg-inverse  w-50 ml-auto mr-auto" data-ride="carousel" >
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" >
    <div class="carousel-item active" >
      <img class="d-block w-100"  src="img\core-img\cup1.jpg"  alt="First slide"  >
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img\core-img\cup2.jpg"  alt="Second slide" >
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img\core-img\cup3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img\core-img\cup4.jpg" alt="Fourth slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change your class from:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide bg-inverse  w-50 ml-auto mr-auto" data-ride="carousel" >
```

to:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
```